# Stuck pixel on X

Tags: xorg, x11

Every couple of days, a pixel roughly in the center of my screen gets stuck on white. It can be unstuck by restarting X, or by logging out and back in. However it remains stuck when I call xrefresh.

Is there any way of getting X to do a harder refresh than just calling xrefresh, but something short of restarting X (which kills all programs)? Or any ideas about the actual nature of the problem?

This is xubuntu 14.04, video is Mobile Intel® GMA 4500MHD.

Answer (score 1):

I do have a dead pixel on my screen that can disappear by gently pressing the screen or by rebooting perhaps it is a dead pixel.

Try to find if it is a dead pixel.

You can set the screen to a lower resolution.

- If the spot is bigger the problem is a display bug.
- If the size didn't change, your screen has a "dead pixel"

You can also boot another Linux distrib on a live USB :

- If the spot never appears you have a display bug

Comment: It probably isn't a dead pixel if it's fixed by simply restarting Xorg.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I suggested that because I have a dead pixel on my screan that can disappear by gently pressing the screen or by rebooting.

Comment: Changing the resolution was a good idea. Turns out, the "stuck" pixel moves when the resolution is changed, confirming beyond doubt that's a display bug, not a real stuck pixel.

Answer (score 0):

I have now figured out that the stuck pixel is caused by Citrix. It's some kind of bug in the way Citrix interacts with X I guess.